# how to use css files spring

Tags: css, spring

am developing a java web application using netbeans ide(jdk 1.6, tomcat 7, mysql, spring 3.0.2, hibernate).I have a multiactioncontroller named 'maincon'. In web.xml, the home page is set as redirect.jsp. the redirect.jsp will redirect the request to index page with the help of multiaction controller. now how can I use css files in this index.jsp
I have a 'indexpageStyle.css' file in the WEB-INF/resources/styles/. if more information is required to answer this, please ask.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do not have direct access to resources under WEB-INF; if you really need it there (which would be weird) you'll need to stream it back yourself.

Otherwise, move it out of there, include it as a regular CSS resource, but generate the file's path using  or the Spring equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this inside jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/source/css/reset.css">
```